# Passing attributes in a jade mixin

Tags: pug

In older versions of jade you could pass the attributes of a mixin on to a block within it like so:

```
mixin a
    a(attributes=attributes)
        block

+a(href='foo')
    | Bar
```

however this now results in

```
<a attributes="[object Object]">Bar</a>
```

instead of

```
<a attributes="foo">Bar</a>
```

Other failed attempts to get this working are shown below. Does anyone know what the new syntax is?

**Attempt 2**

```
mixin a
    a(attributes)
        block

+a(href='foo')
    | Bar
```

Result:

```
<a attributes="attributes">Bar</a>
```

**Attempt 3**

```
mixin a
    a()(attributes)
        block

+a(href='foo')
    | Bar
```

Result:

```
<a attributes="attributes">Bar</a>
```

**Attempt 4**

```
mixin a
    a()(attributes=attributes)
        block

+a(href='foo')
    | Bar
```

Result:

```
<a attributes="[object Object]">Bar</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

It now looks like you use

```
mixin a
    a&attributes(attributes)
        block

+a(href='foo')
    | Bar
```

and https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1294 serves as the documentation.