# Inheriting attributes in Jade mixins

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Is it possible to have a Jade mixin call pass through the attributes passed to the current mixin? Example:

```
mixin A()
    A=attributes.x

mixin B()
    +A
    B=attributes.x

+B()(x="test")
```

It outputs:

```
<A></A>
<B>test</B>
```

Because the attribute `x` doesn't get passed through to `A`. This is desired in most cases. But in my case, I would like to pass through any attributes passed to `B` into `A`, without having to list them a priori (i.e. `+A()(x=attributes.x)`.

Is this possible?

This question is similar to [Passing attributes in a jade mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599006/passing-attributes-in-a-jade-mixin) But the answer posted there does not work as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles upon this, Forbes Lindesay from the Jade Google group answered the question. It can be done this way:

```
mixin A()
  | #{attributes.x}

mixin B()
  +A()&attributes(attributes)

+B()(x=“x”)
```